# how to delete document without deleting collection in firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to create some kind of collection which cannot be deleted. The reason I made it like that is because when the document is empty my website can't do the data creation process
[image]

is it possible to create a collection in firestore that has an empty document?

i use python firebase_admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firestore, there is no such thing as an "empty collection".  Collections simply appear in the console when there is a document present, and disappear when the last document is deleted.  If you want to know if a collection is "empty", then you can simply query it and check that it has 0 documents.

Ideally, your code should be robust enough to handle the possibility of a missing document, because Firestore will do nothing to stop a document from being deleted if that's what you do in the console or your code.